# Выборка MySQL. Ошибка?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть такой запрос к MySQL

```
SELECT *,
   COALESCE(SUM(p.statusp=0),0) '0',
   COALESCE(SUM(p.statusp=1),0) '1',
   COALESCE(SUM(p.statusp=2),0) '2',
   COALESCE(SUM(p.statusp=3),0) '3' FROM z 
LEFT JOIN p ON z.idz=p.idzp GROUP BY z.idz
  ORDER BY z.idz DESC
```

так код проходит без ошибок, но мне нужен отбор по автору

```
WHERE idavtorz=43
```

то есть в итоге получаем

```
SELECT *,
   COALESCE(SUM(p.statusp=0),0) '0',
   COALESCE(SUM(p.statusp=1),0) '1',
   COALESCE(SUM(p.statusp=2),0) '2',
   COALESCE(SUM(p.statusp=3),0) '3' FROM z 
LEFT JOIN p ON z.idz=p.idzp GROUP BY z.idz
WHERE idavtorz=43  ORDER BY z.idz DESC
```

выдает ошибку

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE idavtorz = 43 ORDER BY z.idz DESC

Подскажите, в чем ошибка?

Comment: GROUP BY z.idz и WHERE idavtorz=43 не меняли местами?

Comment: поменял, работает!!! Благодарю!